# vpnc Not Adding Internal DNS Servers to resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, vpn, dns, vpnc

I'm trying to setup vpnc on Ubuntu.  When I run `vpnc`, my resolv.conf file does not get changed.  It still only contains my ISP's name servers:

```
#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact
nameserver 65.32.5.111
nameserver 65.32.5.112
```

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 65.32.5.111 65.32.5.112
```

Any tips on how to troubleshoot/resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install ***resolvconf*** ?

If you did, try removing it and see if it works.

Comment: @Studer - bingo, that fixed it.  I wonder why `apt-get install vpnc` requires resolvconf, but you can just uninstall resolvconf?  Odd...

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember this being a problem. On the **Editting *[vpn name]*** dialog box, **IPv4 Settings** tab, my Method is set to **Automatic (VPN)**, rather then "Automatic (VPN) addresses only", and name resolution to the internal network worked fine.

Comment: @EricJLN - "dialog box"...I'm just using the vpnc command in a terminal. I'm guessing there's a config file setting that maps to what you're referencing in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

@AJ. the answer could come too late, but the question is always valid: to force a DNS configuration in a VPN managed by Network Manager, other than use GUI tools, you could open the file:

```
   /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<NetworkManager_VPN_name>
```

and, in section:

```
   [ipv4]
```

add:

```
   dns=10.31.57.70
```

Another method is to configure dnsmasq directly:

in the file:

```
   /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

add (for example) a line:

```
   server=/10.in-addr-arpa/<VPN_DNS_IP_ADDRESS>
```

to forward all DNS requests for all hosts in network 10. to the DNS specified

then, of course, restart dnsmasq:

```
   $ sudo service dnsmasq restart
```